# C how to pack mutex lock access to a structure inside a function

Tags: c, struct, mutex

I have a code that implements threads that share a series of simple counters and I grouped them in a structure to tidy up the code a litle bit. So now I have to access the counters inside the structure by its name but at the same time lock the structure wiht a mutex. So far so good no problem there, but for maintenence reasons, and code simplicity I will like to pack the mutex lock of the structure and the access to any of its members in a function , where I use as input argument the name of the member that i wish to read or change.

I dont know if this is posible, or even convenient, I mean using a single mutex for all the counters shared by all threads may be a bad idea, givin the fact that a single counter is usually used by only two threads.

So thats why I came here to get opinions about this and tips on how could this be acomplished

---

In order to explain better what I'm looking for.

I Have a struct of counters that is shared on different threads

```
struct SHARED_DATA
{
 unsigned int counter1;
 unsigned int counter2;
 unsigned int counter3;
}
```

Let´s say that the structure is defined global

```
struct SHARED_DATA shared_data = {0};
```

So, I have to access the counters individually, but I would like to pack the access to the members while simultaneusly lock the structure whit a mutex, all of this inside of a function which input argument is the name of the member of the structure that I want to read or update. Something like this

```
unsigned int Read_Counters(const char counter)
{
 unsigned int value;
 pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_shared_data);
 value = shared_data.counter;
 pthread_mutex_unlock(pthread_mutex_shared_data);
 return value;
}
```

Comment: This is difficult to answer without more context and some code.

Comment: I know. I expanded my question, hope is more clear now

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood your problem.

If I understand correctly, you do NOT want a single mutex for the whole structure, and you want the mutex to be packed INSIDE the structure.

you could do something like this:

```
typedef struct{ 
    int shared1;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex1;
    int shared2;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex2;
} shared_resources;

void touch_shared_esources(shared_resources* shared_things) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_things->mutex1);
    shared_things->shared1++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_things->mutex1);
}
```

EDIT:

so, you want to have a function in charge of reading value of the struct, right?

you could do something like this:

```
void read() {
    static pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    // do things to shared data
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. That's not what I tried to explain, I expanded my question in orden to be more clear on what I'm looking

Comment: Sure, but also I want to call this function from any thread , so I need a way to tell wich element of the structure I'm going to read and also a return value from the function

Comment: It's ok. you can easily modify the function to return. and about telling it which element you want to touch - you could either define multiple functions or give an argument to the function. the arg can be an integer = 1,2,3 or even a pointer to the shared resource (&shared_bundle->elm1 or something like that)